# ERROR: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

Tags: database, postgresql, phoenix-framework

I'm rocking a Phoenix app, and when I try to run `mix ecto.migrate`, I encounter the following error:

```
GenServer #PID<0.181.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL (invalid_authorization_specification): no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
```

There's some Q&A out there that touches on this particular error, but I haven't found them to be useful, unfortunately. So I turn here!

Additional environment info: Mac OS X, Postgres.app, PG version 9.5

Answer (score 17):

I had to upgrade from pg_dump 15.4 to 16.1.

On MacOS: `brew install libpq`

I do not have postgres installed with brew as that runs in Docker.

Comment: for me i had to run ```brew upgrade``` to make above ```brew install libpq``` take effect to fix the issues.  maybe because i had the libpg installed before.

Comment: here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/155651#issuecomment-1830261308

Answer (score 6):

The *StartupMessage* sent from the client to the server must contain a non-empty user name; as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-message-formats.html) says:

> StartupMessage (F)
>
> [...]
>
> The protocol version number is followed by one or more pairs of parameter name and value strings. A zero byte is required as a terminator after the last name/value pair. Parameters can appear in any order. user is required, others are optional. [...]

My guess is that you specified an empty user name.

Comment: wow, how about the error message instead saying that that is required...

Comment: so, how do you do that in the actual code?  Knowing the why is nice, but how do you resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

if you did not create a new user, the default is your mac username and password.

This is coming late but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the typo of your environment variable, in my case I used `PSQLS_USERNAME` (extra S because I renamed from POSTGRES to PSQL to make it shorter) as environment variable and `PSQL_USERNAME`  in the connection row.

So I ended-up with a block of code that was properly formatted except the typo in the environment variable name (they are not underlined by the Code Editor).